# Get project level connection managers from C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am currently working a C# console application where i want to execute certain SSIS packages that is part of a SSIS project.

The problem here is that some of the connection managers in the SSIS package is at project level and some on package level.

**Console app:**

```
Package pkg;
Application app;
DTSExecResult pkgResults;

app = new Application();
pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

PrintPackageInfo(pkg);

pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

PrintOutput(pkgResults, pkg);
```

**Error Output:**

```
The connection <connectionid> is not found. This error is thrown by Connection collection when the specific connection element is not found.
```

However when i loop over the `Connections` for the `pkg` object like this

```
foreach(ConnectionManager con in pkg.Connections)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t Connection Manager {0}", con.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("\t Connection String {0}", con.ConnectionString);
}
```

it outputs the package level connection managers but not the connection managers at project level.

Comment: Do any of your package-level connection managers share the same name as your project ones?

Comment: No all connection managers have unique names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Project level connections, then I assume you have the ispac file available. If so, you can use the [Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.project.aspx) class to open the ispac file using one of the OpenProject methods. Once you open the project, you can access the ConnectionManagerItems of that project and iterate through them as needed.

An example using file storage for an ispac:

```
string ispacFile = @"C:\Temp\ssis_project.ispac";
Project prj = Project.OpenProject(ispacFile);
foreach(ConnectionManagerItem conn in prj.ConnectionManagerItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(conn.StreamName);
    // other operations as needed
}
```

Comment: Even though i wanted to do this at a package level with only importing the project level connections instead of the whole ispac file, i finally realized that this was the smoother and more cleaner way to go, thanks!